# Facebook : Profile Expression Kit give error

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

Whenever I try to upload profile picture or profile video in iPhone the gives error,

> Error Uploading video Please try again/cant change profile picture
>   Please try again.

I have followed the step mentioned below,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios#download

Please help me to fix issue.